# How Safari list all JSContexts?

Tags: macos, safari, webkit, ios-simulator, javascriptcore

Safari can show JSContexts from third part desktop applications as well as iOS simulators. Are there OS level APIs for registering and querying JSContexts?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can only create your own.
I also cannot imagine that they would add this any time soon if at all since this could lead to extreme harm for the end user (passwords or other sensitive data without the user even knowing could be processed in the background).